# Envoking function during unchecking checkbox - script CS6 64 bit Photoshop - Bug

Tags: javascript, photoshop

[image]

I have functionality, when you checked box "Same Height and Width" `var constrainsProportions` enables coping values from Height `grpHeight.numb` to Width `grpWidth.numb` and vice versa, when you passed some value into. 
This is invoked in `grpWidth.numb.onChange = function()` and `grpHeight.numb.onChange = function()` respectively. 
**And it works**.

[image]
[image]

Also when you check box, it takes highest values and pass it to second one.
This is invoked in condition `if (constrainsProportions.value == true)`
**And it works also**.
[image]
[image]

Bug is when during passing values in any `edittext`(you do not hit enter or exit editing),you click checkbox. It takes again highest value and pass it to second one.

**It shouldn't work**. Any value shouldn't be changed.

[image]
[image]

**Even when** `constrainsProportions.value` **is** `false` when you hit checkbox second time. And `grpWidth.numb.onChange()` else `grpHeight.numb.onChange` in this condition should not be invoked
Not sure where is error.

code

```
#target photoshop

var mainWindow = new Window("dialog", "dynamic changing values");

var grpUnitVal = mainWindow.add("group")

var constrainsProportions = grpUnitVal.add("checkbox", undefined, "Same Height and Width");

//Edittext: Height
var grpHeight = mainWindow.add("group")
grpHeight.text = grpHeight.add("statictext", undefined, "Height: ");
grpHeight.numb =  grpHeight.add("edittext", undefined, 0);
grpHeight.numb.characters = 9;

//Edittext: Width
var grpWidth = mainWindow.add("group")
grpWidth.text = grpWidth.add("statictext", undefined, "Width:  ");
grpWidth.numb =  grpWidth.add("edittext", undefined, 0);
grpWidth.numb.characters = 9;

//Edittext: Width; if "constrains proportion" is checked, Heigth and Width values are changed in the same time
grpWidth.numb.onChange = function() {
    if (constrainsProportions.value == true){
        grpHeight.numb.text = grpWidth.numb.text;}
    }

//Edittext: Height; if "constrains proportion" is checked, Heigth and Width values are changed in the same time
grpHeight.numb.onChange = function() {
    if (constrainsProportions.value == true){
        grpWidth.numb.text = grpHeight.numb.text;}
    }

constrainsProportions.onClick = function() {

    //Set the same heighest value in Height and Width
    alert(constrainsProportions.value);
    if (constrainsProportions.value == true){
        if (parseInt(grpWidth.numb.text, 10) > parseInt(grpHeight.numb.text, 10)) {
             grpWidth.numb.onChange();} 
        else {
            grpHeight.numb.onChange();}
            }
}


mainWindow.show();
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because `onChange()` event is sent when the control loses focus, not when you type, so the code gets a previous version of what you see on the panel. Use `onChanging` instead:

```
#target photoshop

var mainWindow = new Window("dialog", "dynamic changing values");

var grpUnitVal = mainWindow.add("group")

var constrainsProportions = grpUnitVal.add("checkbox", undefined, "Same Height and Width");

//Edittext: Height
var grpHeight = mainWindow.add("group")
grpHeight.text = grpHeight.add("statictext", undefined, "Height: ");
grpHeight.numb =  grpHeight.add("edittext", undefined, 0);
grpHeight.numb.characters = 9;

//Edittext: Width
var grpWidth = mainWindow.add("group")
grpWidth.text = grpWidth.add("statictext", undefined, "Width:  ");
grpWidth.numb =  grpWidth.add("edittext", undefined, 0);
grpWidth.numb.characters = 9;

//Edittext: Width; if "constrains proportion" is checked, Heigth and Width values are changed in the same time
grpWidth.numb.onChanging = function() {
    if (constrainsProportions.value){
        grpHeight.numb.text = this.text;}
    }

//Edittext: Height; if "constrains proportion" is checked, Heigth and Width values are changed in the same time
grpHeight.numb.onChanging = function() {
    if (constrainsProportions.value){
        grpWidth.numb.text = this.text;}
    }

constrainsProportions.onClick = function() {

    //Set the same heighest value in Height and Width
    // alert(constrainsProportions.value);
    if (this.value){
        if (parseInt(grpWidth.numb.text, 10) > parseInt(grpHeight.numb.text, 10)) {
             grpHeight.numb.text = grpWidth.numb.text;} 
        else {
            grpWidth.numb.text = grpHeight.numb.text;}
            }
}


mainWindow.show();
```